# Google Translate Element click function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using google translation in my webpage. But some person names could not be translated as exactly. so, i want to use this following function to show the name in English and Tamil.. I want to get name changes while click google elements of language buttons.  please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ta">
<head>
<title>Language Translation</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            /*google translation will show select box and show original 
             button  and translate buttons those all are google elements
             i mean*/
    $(googleElements).on('click', function(){

            var txt = $("#TamilEng").text();

             if(txt=="தமிழ்"){ 
                   $("#Tamil").show();
                   $("#Eng").hide();
                   return false;
                   }
             if(txt=="Tamil"){
                  $("#Tamil").hide();
                  $("#Eng").show();
                 return false;
            }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div  id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
          function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ta', includedLanguages: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<div id="TamilEng">தமிழ்</div>
<input id="Tamil" type="text" value="நன்றி">
<input id="Eng" type="text" value="Welcome"  style="display:none;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `GoogleElement`?

Comment: You should change to `$("#google_translate_element").on('click', function(){`...

Comment: google translation will show select box and show original button and translate buttons those all are google elements i mean